# How do I solve "Failed to find data adapter that can handle input" error for a multi-input Keras model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to build a Keras multi-input model that takes both images and 1D protein sequences.

The 1D sequences have the form:

```
train_protein = tf.expand_dims(padded_train_protein_encode,axis=2)
print(train_protein.shape) #(5411, 1500, 1)
```

I have images that are like this:

```
for file in images[:1]:
  im = cv2.imread(os.path.join(folder_train_val,file))

  print(type(im)) #<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
  print(im.shape) #(500, 500, 3)
```

I've saved the paths to the images in a dataframe, and I am trying to use tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator to input the images, like this:

```
train_datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

batch_size = 32

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    train_df,
    x_col="paths",
    y_col=["Label"],
    batch_size=batch_size,
    shuffle='False',
    class_mode='raw')


val_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    validation_df,
    x_col="paths",
    y_col=["Label"],
    batch_size=batch_size,
    shuffle='False',
    class_mode='raw')
```

I have written the following model:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Conv1D, GlobalMaxPooling1D, MaxPooling1D, Embedding, Concatenate, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, GlobalMaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.utils  import plot_model
from tensorflow.keras import Input

H = W = 500

protein_input = Input(shape=(train_protein.shape[1:]))
image_input = Input(shape=(H,W,3))

#protein layers
x = Conv1D(filters=32, padding="valid", activation="relu", strides=1, kernel_size=4)(protein_input)
x = Conv1D(filters=64, padding="valid", activation="relu", strides=1, kernel_size=8)(x)
x = Conv1D(filters=96, padding="valid", activation="relu", strides=1, kernel_size=12)(x)
final_protein = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(x)

#image layers
y = Conv2D(filters=32, padding="valid", activation="relu", strides=1, kernel_size=4)(image_input)
y = Conv2D(filters=64, padding="valid", activation="relu", strides=1, kernel_size=6)(y)
y = Conv2D(filters=96, padding="valid", activation="relu", strides=1, kernel_size=8)(y)
final_image = GlobalMaxPooling2D()(y)

join = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([final_protein, final_image], axis=-1)


x = Dense(1024, activation="relu")(join)
x = Dropout(0.1)(x)
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.1)(x)
x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)

predictions = Dense(1,kernel_initializer='normal')(x)

model = Model(inputs=[protein_input, image_input], outputs=[predictions])

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mean_absolute_error', cindex_score])

history = model.fit(
    x=[train_protein, train_generator], y=log_labels,
    validation_data=([val_protein, val_generator], log_labels),
    epochs=150, batch_size=32)
```

Which cause the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-120f9289a3bc> in <module>()
      5         x=[train_protein, train_generator], y=log_training_Kd_labels,
      6         validation_data=([val_protein, val_generator], log_validation_Kd_labels),
----> 7     epochs=150, batch_size=32)
      8 
      9 model_folder = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/models'

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in select_data_adapter(x, y)
    992         "Failed to find data adapter that can handle "
    993         "input: {}, {}".format(
--> 994             _type_name(x), _type_name(y)))
    995   elif len(adapter_cls) > 1:
    996     raise RuntimeError(

ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>", "<class 'tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image.DataFrameIterator'>"}), <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Is this because of the way I am using ImageDataGenerator?
Is this type of multi-input model possible?

Update:

I now have this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Conv1D, GlobalMaxPooling1D, MaxPooling1D, Embedding, Concatenate, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, GlobalMaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.utils  import plot_model
from tensorflow.keras import Input

def get_images(image_path):
 byte_file = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
 img = tf.image.decode_png(byte_file) 
 return img

image_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((df['paths']))
image_dataset = image_dataset.map(get_images)

protein_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((padded_train_protein)) #type(padded_train_protein) numpy.ndarray

val_protein_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((padded_val_protein))
#type(padded_val_protein) numpy.ndarray
target_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((log_training_Kd_labels))
#type(log_training_Kd_labels) numpy.ndarray
val_target_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((log_validation_Kd_labels))
#type(log_validation_Kd_labels) numpy.ndarray

H = W = 500

protein_shape = tf.expand_dims(padded_train_protein_encode,axis=2) #TensorShape([1500, 1])

protein_input = Input(shape=(protein_shape.shape[1:]))
compound_input = Input(shape=(H,W,3))

#protein layers
x = Conv1D(filters=32, padding="valid", activation="relu", strides=1, kernel_size=4)(protein_input)
x = Conv1D(filters=64, padding="valid", activation="relu", strides=1, kernel_size=8)(x)
x = Conv1D(filters=96, padding="valid", activation="relu", strides=1, kernel_size=12)(x)
final_protein = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(x)

#compound layers
y = Conv2D(filters=32, padding="valid", activation="relu", strides=1, kernel_size=4)(compound_input)
y = Conv2D(filters=64, padding="valid", activation="relu", strides=1, kernel_size=6)(y)
y = Conv2D(filters=96, padding="valid", activation="relu", strides=1, kernel_size=8)(y)
#final_compound = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(y)
final_compound = GlobalMaxPooling2D()(y)

join = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([final_protein, final_compound], axis=-1)


x = Dense(1024, activation="relu")(join)
x = Dropout(0.1)(x)
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.1)(x)
x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)

predictions = Dense(1,kernel_initializer='normal')(x)

model = Model(inputs=[protein_input, compound_input], outputs=[predictions])

import os
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mean_absolute_error', cindex_score])

history = model.fit(
    x=[protein_dataset, image_dataset], y=target_dataset,
    validation_data=([val_protein_dataset, val_target_dataset], val_target_dataset),
    epochs=150, batch_size=32)
```

Which causes the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-379e9cdb7f4c> in <module>()
      8         x=[protein_dataset, image_dataset], y=target_dataset,
      9         validation_data=([val_protein_dataset, val_target_dataset], val_target_dataset),
---> 10     epochs=150, batch_size=32)
     11 
     12 model_folder = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/models'

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in select_data_adapter(x, y)
    992         "Failed to find data adapter that can handle "
    993         "input: {}, {}".format(
--> 994             _type_name(x), _type_name(y)))
    995   elif len(adapter_cls) > 1:
    996     raise RuntimeError(

ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.MapDataset'>", "<class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.TensorSliceDataset'>"}), <class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.TensorSliceDataset'>
```

Answer (score 0):

This type of multi-input model is possible it's just that you are using a tensor as the first input and a generator object in the second input. You would have to change the format of the input. You can use the `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices` to create all the three inputs `train_protein`, `train_images` and `trian_labels`.
Try the below method.
example 1) -

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

data = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=305, n_classes=3, n_clusters_per_class=1)
inputs = data[0]
tragets = data[1]

def change_shape(inputs, labels): # In your case you will load the image here
    first = inputs[0]
    first = tf.reshape(first, (10,10,3))
    return ((first, inputs[1]), labels)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(((inputs[:, :300], inputs[:, 300:]), data[1]))
dataset = dataset.map(change_shape)
dataset = dataset.batch(20)

inputa = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape = (10,10,3))
inputb = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape = (5))

conva = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(15, 3, activation='relu')(inputa)
layera = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(conva)

layerb = tf.keras.layers.Dense(15, activation='relu')(inputb)

concat = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([layera, layerb])

out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')(concat)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[inputa, inputb], outputs=[out])

model.compile(
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(), #or categorical_crossentropy
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics = ['accuracy']
              )

model.fit(dataset, epochs=2)
```

If any error comes then do comment.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the first option and I got a `AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v2.io' has no attribute 'readfile'` error. I have installed tensorflow as tf, why have I got this error? (I am using google colab)

Comment: Dude just look up this error on google. There was just a `_` missing from my function. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Hey, I don't understand why I still have the same error, when I have used `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slice` on all the Inputs. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: I have updated the answer. Hope you can understand. Also, you have to modify the change_shape to your read_image function.

Comment: My model is for regression. How do I adapt your answer for a regression problem?

Comment: You need to change the activation in the last Dense layer to `linear` and then change the loss to a regression loss say `RMSE` and just remove the metric.